# Numbers randomly placed with images hovering

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a question about a webpage.
I want to put numbers at random on a page, like a postit-wall-thing. Just numbers. When I hover over one number it should show an image. The images can never be shown over the number.

Like in below image, can anyone tell me the best way of placing numbers like this? I feel like paddings and margins are not the best way, but I don't know what is
[image: And when I hover, the image should never place itself over the number. It doesn't matter if it's over another number, but not the one it is bound to.]

And when I hover, the image should never place itself over the number. It doesn't matter if it's over another number, but not the one it is bound to.
[image: And when I hover, the image should never place itself over the number. It doesn't matter if it's over another number, but not the one it is bound to.]

I'm not asking anyone to do this math for me, just how I should be thinking. A smart way to solve this.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far to make this yourself

Comment: Please provide some of your code to see what you have done

Comment: Take random number from screen resolution x & y and assign them as absolute position for each number.

Comment: Ok ok, ill post it in a codepen link: https://codepen.io/yrrving/pen/PeOZLN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Enter number of tiles you want and add show picture instead of changing `backgournd-color`.

This code create a random order of numbers.

```js
function start() {
  var maxNumber = 8,
    div = "",
    array = [];

  while (array.length < maxNumber) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    if ($.inArray(x, array) == -1) {
      array.push(x);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
    div += "<div class='row'>";
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      div += `<div class='col-xs-4 tile' id='${"div-"+i}'>${array[i]}</div>`;
      if (j < 2) i++;
      if (i >= maxNumber) break;
    }
    div += "</div>";
    if (i + 1 >= maxNumber) break;
  }

  $("#numberPanel").append(div);

  for (var i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
    $("#div-" + i).on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
    $("#div-" + i).on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
  }
}

start();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.tile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 85px;
  max-height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <div id="numberPanel">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is not what you want, right? :D @NicklasKarlsson

Comment: It is a start of what i want to create :) i need to place the Numbers more like in my posted images, then i need hovereffects for the Numbers, where They should show images besides the Numbers. But i love the jQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and use javascript:

```
document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "1.jpg";
```